# 3-to-8 Demultiplexer in TikZ/CircuiTikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I'm trying to draw something like this in TikZ/[CircuiTikZ](https://ctan.org/pkg/circuitikz). The package documentation seems to be really well-kept and extensive but there's only a few full examples (rather split into little chunks that you need to put together). I am pretty new to TikZ, however, so it did not make much sense for me yet.

[image]

Comment: The tutorial about the logic circuit should help you to start. Please start from there, and if get stuck post your partial result and we'll try to help. Perpendicular coordinate system will be your friend here (there is a reference to the right place to look at in the circuitikz manual, at the start of the tutorial section). Like it is now, this question seems too much a "please do it for me" one...

Comment: @millionmilesaway please see if the answer below suits the requirement

Comment: @jsbibra It does. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.US} % TiKZ Library for US Logic Circuits.
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta, calc}


\begin{document}

\def\L{-2cm}
\begin{circuitikz}[circuit logic US, every circuit symbol/.style={ultra thick},line width=1.5pt]
    
    \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \k using int(\i-1)] in {1,2,3,...,8} {
        \node   [and gate,
                inputs={nnnn}, 
                ] 
                    (and\i)         at          (0,\i*\L)                           {};
        \draw       (and\i)--++(1,0) node[label={right:\bfseries\texttt Y\k}]       {};
    }
    
        \node   [and gate,inputs={nnn}, 
                below left=0.2cm and 4.5cm of and2 ] 
                    (andL)                                                          {};
    
    \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \k using int(\i-5)] in {6,7,8} {
        \node   [not gate, 
                left=2cm of and\i.input 4 ] 
                    (not\k)                                                         {};
    }   
    
    \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \k using int(\i+3)] in {1,2,3} {
        \node   [not gate, 
                left=4cm of not\i] 
                    (not\k)                                                         {};
    }
    
        \node   [not gate, 
                left=1.5cm of andL.input 2] 
                    (not7)                                                          {};
        \node   [not gate, 
                above=1cm of not7] 
                    (not8)                                                          {};
        \node   [buffer gate, 
                below=1cm of not7] 
                    (buffer)                                                        {};
    
    \foreach \i/\j in {6/A2,5/A1,4/A0,7/E2,8/E1} {
        \draw       (not\i)--++(-1,0) node[label={left:\bfseries\texttt \j}]        {};
    }
    
        \draw       (buffer)--++(-1,0) node[label={left:\bfseries\texttt  E3}]      {};
        \draw       (andL.input 1)-- ++(left:7mm) |- (not8);
        \draw       (andL.input 2)-- ++(left:7mm) |- (not7);
        \draw       (andL.input 3)-- ++(left:7mm) |- (buffer);

    \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \k using int(\i-3)]in {6,5,4} {
        \draw       (not\i)--(not\k);
    }
        \draw [red] (and1.input 4) -- 
                    ++(left:3mm)                                                    coordinate(redwire)  
                                    |-      (and2.input 4) to   [short, -*]
                    ++(left:3mm)    |-      (and3.input 4) to   [short, -*]
                    ++(left:3mm)    |-      (and4.input 4) to   [short, -*]
                    ++(left:3mm)    |-      (and5.input 4) to   [short, -*]
                    ++(left:3mm)    |-      (and6.input 4) to   [short, -*]
                    ++(left:3mm)    |-      (and7.input 4) to   [short, -*]
                    ++(left:3mm)    |-      (and8.input 1);
        \draw [blue]  (and5.input 3) -- 
                    ++(left:6mm)                                                coordinate(bluewire)  
                                    |-      (and6.input 2) to   [short, -*]
                    ++(left:6mm)    |-      (and7.input 2) to   [short, -*]
                    ++(left:6mm)    |-      (and8.input 4) ;
        \draw [green] (and3.input 2) -- 
                    ++(left:9mm)                                                coordinate(greenwire)  
                                    |-      (and4.input 2) to   [short, -*]
                    ++(left:9mm)    |-      (and7.input 3) to   [short, -*]
                    ++(left:9mm)    |-      (and8.input 2) ;    
        \draw [brown] (and2.input 1)                        to  [short, -*]
                    ++(left:12mm)                                               coordinate(brownwire) 
                                    |-      (and4.input 1) to   [short, -*]
                    ++(left:12mm)   |-      (and6.input 3) to   [short, -*]
                    ++(left:12mm)   |-      (and8.input 3);
        \draw let   \p1=(brownwire),
                    \p2=(not1.output) in 
                    (not1.output)                           to  [short,-*] 
                    ++($(\x1,0)-(\x2,0)$);
        \draw let   \p1=(greenwire),
                    \p2=(not2.output) in 
                    (not2.output)                           to  [short,-*] 
                    ++($(\x1,0)-(\x2,0)$);
        \draw let   \p1=(bluewire),
                    \p2=(not3.output) in 
                    (not3.output)                           to  [short,-*] 
                    ++($(\x1,0)-(\x2,0)$);
        \draw let   \p1=(redwire),
                    \p2=(andL.output) in 
                    (andL.output)                           to  [short,-*] 
                    ++($(\x1,0)-(\x2,0)$);
        
        \draw       (not3.input)                            to  [short,-*] 
                    ++(left:3mm)                                                coordinate(not3)
                    (not2.input)                            to  [short,-*] 
                    ++(left:6mm)                                                coordinate(not2)
                    (not1.input)                            to  [short,-*] 
                    ++(left:9mm)                                                coordinate(not1)
                                                            to  [short,-*] 
                    ++(left:3mm)                                                coordinate(not11);
            \draw[blue](not11)      |-      (and7.input 1);
    \foreach \i/\k in {1/not1,2/not2,3/not3} {
        \draw[red] (and1.input \i)  -|      (\k);
    }
    \foreach \i/\k in {not2/and2.input 2, not3/and2.input 3} {
        \draw[brown] let    \p1=(\i),
                            \p2=(\k) in (\k)                to  [short,-*] 
                            ++($(\x1,0)-(\x2,0)$);
    }
    \foreach \i/\k in {not1/and3.input 1, not3/and3.input 3} {
        \draw[green] let    \p1=(\i),
                            \p2=(\k) in (\k)                to  [short,-*] 
                            ++($(\x1,0)-(\x2,0)$);
    }
    \foreach \i/\k in {not3/and4.input 3} {
        \draw[NavyBlue] let     \p1=(\i),
                                \p2=(\k) in (\k)            to  [short,-*] 
                                ++($(\x1,0)-(\x2,0)$);
    }
    \foreach \i/\k in {not1/and5.input 1, not2/and5.input 2} {
        \draw[blue] let         \p1=(\i),
                                \p2=(\k) in (\k)            to  [short,-*] 
                                ++($(\x1,0)-(\x2,0)$);
    }
    \foreach \i/\k in {not2/and6.input 1} {
        \draw[SeaGreen] let     \p1=(\i),
                                \p2=(\k) in (\k)            to [short,-*] 
                                ++($(\x1,0)-(\x2,0)$);
    }
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```